# Taking width attribute from children elements

Tags: jquery

This is my first jQuery code. I want my ul element with class ".topnav" to have value of width attribute from the most width attribute li element that it contains. I have code like this and css for li elements `display:none`:

```
$(function(){
    $('.topnav').each(function(){
      $(this).attr('width', Math.max($(this).children().each(function(){$(this).attr('width')})))});
   })
```

But it isn't work. Does someone could help?

Comment: Do your `li` elements have widths specified? If not they'll expand to fill the width of the `ul` and will all have the same width, which may well cause you a problem.

Comment: No, my li elements don't have specified widths. They shouldn't because li elements are filled dynamically through django. So maybe in future there become new li element with widhest word. So I need all ul elements to fit to the widthes li element.

Comment: Have a look at this to see what I mean: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/6bGSY/). `li` elements 1 and 2 both return the width of the `ul`, not their own widths.

Comment: It is something like I needed but not exacly that.

Comment: @Cris: It wasn't a solution, it was a demo of what happens when widths aren't specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, it's hard to understand your question. Did you mean, you want your ul's width to be the same as the widest li? If so, do you want to include the padding/border/margin of the li?

Instead of using attr('width'), use width([value]) or outerWidth([value]) to get/set your width.

A lot of other mistake in the code, your `$(this).children().each` does not return the width. Hang on, let me whip something out real quick, plz hold.

Here you go:

```
var maxWidth = Math.max.apply(Math, $('.topnav > li').map(function(){ return $(this).width(); }).get());
$('.topnav').width(maxWidth);
```

The `map` function 'converts' the array of li into an array of its width. `get` converts it into regular Javascript array. Then you apply the function `max` passing it `Math` as the scope in the first argument and the array in the second argument.

Comment: This work perfectly. Thanks because I just start to using jQuery. I will study Your working code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxwidth = 0;
$('.topnav').each(function(){
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        if($(this).width() > maxwidth){
            maxwidth = $(this).width();
        }
    });
});
```

Then you would set the width of `.topnav` to `maxwidth`.

Comment: This did not work for me. Maybe I do something wrong or don't say eneught clearly wha is on my mind. But thanks for help :)

Comment: It seems to should working in my app but not working. Code above from Pixelfreak works.